# Split a string in a special way

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have this String: `"player.login name=username;x=52;y=406"` how would I be able to split it so I easily could do `Player pl = new Player(name, x, y)` ?

I tried with a regex that looks like this: `"([a-zA-Z_]+)[=]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[;]{1}"` but I'm not very good at regexs so it didn't work.

EDIT: Someone came up with a good solution so no need to comment. :)

What I used:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String login = "player.login name=username;x=52;y=406";
    String str = login.substring("player.login".length() + 1);
    String[] sp = str.split(";");
    Player player = new Player("", 0, 0);
    for (String s : sp) {
        String[] a = s.split("=");
        if (a[0].equals("name")) player.username = a[1];
        else if (a[0].equals("x")) player.x = toInt(a[1]);
        else if (a[0].equals("y")) player.y = toInt(a[1]);
    }
    System.out.println("Player: " + player.username + " @ " + player.x + ", " + player.y);
}

public static int toInt(String s) {
    return Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

Comment: Why not use StringTokenizer with separators being ` ` and `;` and then split each tokens after the first one on the `=` sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work (you should add bound checks before calling `exp.split("=")[1]`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "player.login name=username;x=52;y=406";
    String[] expressions = s.split(";");
    for (String exp : expressions) {
        System.out.println(exp.split("=")[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works and it the one that works best for what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 7 there is support for named capturing groups, would be a nice usage here

```
String s = "player.login name=username;x=52;y=406";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("name=(?<UserName>[^;]+);" +  // Match the UserName in the Named Group "UserName", matching at least one non semicolon
    "x=(?<x>\\d+);" + // Match the value of x in the Named Group "x", matching at least one digit
    "y=(?<y>\\d+)"    // Match the value of y in the Named Group "y", matching at least one digit
    );
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group("UserName"));
    System.out.println(m.group("x"));
    System.out.println(m.group("y"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String.split()` three times, splitting on a space, then semicolon, then `=`. Or *assylia*'s answer does it with two splits - best solution rather depends on whether you want to validate the parts of the text you are discarding.

Or using regex...

```
String regex = ".+=(\\w+);x=(\\d+);y=(\\d+)"
```

...which you can run with the following code:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+=(\\w+);x=(\\d+);y=(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("player.login name=username;x=52;y=406");
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + "," + m.group(2) + "," + m.group(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try with Guava:

```
String data = "player.login name=username;x=52;y=406";
List<String> fields = ImmutableList.copyOf(Splitter.on(' ').limit(2).split(data));

String type = fields.get(0);
Map<String, String> properties = Splitter.on(';').trimResults().withKeyValueSeparator("=").split(fields.get(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Pattern instead:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String str = "player.login name=username;x=52;y=406";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^player\\.login name=(.+);x=(\\d+);y=(\\d+)$");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

    Player player;
    if (m.matches()){
        String name = m.group(1);
        int x = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
        int y = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));

        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);

        player = new Player(name, x, y);
    } else {
        player = null;
    }

    // Do stuff with player.
}
```